# Dynamic imports or lazy loading is not working with webpack, babel, typescript

Tags: dynamic, babeljs, loading, tsconfig

I want to have a dynamic import functionality included in my project. I have seen where the modules are loaded on-demand with a separate network call to reduce the main bundle size.
However this is not working for me.
My tsconfig.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkblI.png)

My babel.config.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEdII.png)

Stuck on this for too long but not able to make out what might be wrong.